# Can multi-page webform submission be saved after each page?

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

We would like to implement a form on our site that consists of two pages. The first page is the bare minimum amount of information we need to save a valid submission.  The second page is some optional, additional information that supplements the basic information on the first page. If the user fills out the first page, we would like to save the submission, then, if the second page is filled out, update the submission with the additional information.

We are using the Webforms module to manage our forms. I noticed that it has an option to "Save draft" between pages but I don't think this is quite what I'm looking for. The first page should be saved as an actual submission even if they choose not to fill out the second page.

Is this possible with Drupal/Webforms?